# How can I create a list control, jr:list in two columns?

Tags: jasper-reports, multiple-columns

I have a jasper report list control where I am getting dynamic values from the back-end. I need to show the list value in two column.

How can I do that?

Here is my code for the `jr:list`

```
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
    <datasetRun subDataset="accessorialsDataset" uuid="b0e600e0-5797-42b4-8078-12dd4231dd3d">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{accessorialDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:listContents height="12" width="524">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="259" height="12" uuid="221d3ff4-39a7-4ddd-bc74-50bed600819b"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Liberation Sans" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accessorial}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
```

Comment: please use the table with 2 columns

Comment: If I use a table then how can have same field in 2 columns ? If I have two columns then I have only one textelement which I have used to shows the values in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve multiple columns on a `jr:list` component set `printOrder="Horizontal"`, then specify the `jr:listContents` width to be a multiple of the number of columns you need respect to the reportElement containing the `jr:list`

**Example with 2 columns**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="2 columns" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="308cb8ae-e40a-45f4-a347-c6fcdad320b1">
    <subDataset name="Dataset" uuid="ad0d45f0-00f0-495c-bff4-ae70340e05d4">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <summary>
        <band height="30">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="30" uuid="f811df99-b6ad-4157-a818-42ed4b77c2f0"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset" uuid="30dc2e8a-06f9-4ecf-aa8d-66d5edd6fb95">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList("Item1;Item2;Item3;Item4".split(";")))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="275">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="30" uuid="2500a411-7ad6-4148-958f-34dfae2c9346"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

> Note: `printOrder="Horizontal"` and that jr:listContents `width="275"`
>   is 1/2 of the reportElement's `width="550"`

**Output**

[image: result]